# How to set the background of the body of ListView (content part in the middle but not the header or foot)?

Tags: android, listview, background

Here I want to separately set the background of header part and the body part of a ListView, like a rectangle with white background color and light blue bound for each.

But I cannot find the way to set the background for the BODY part of ListView.
When I call the listview.setBackgroundResource(bg), the parameter background wraps the whole of listview, I cannot just set the background of the BODY part.

Comment: Do you want to set the background color of each row ? If so, then you need to override the getView method and set the background of the view

Comment: Sorry but no... I mean to wrap the whole body or list items part of the ListView with a single background, like '口', possibly with divider, like '目'.But not set the backgroud for each row.There may be header view, so it is like '吕' if no divider was set.

Comment: Sorry but no... I mean to wrap the whole body or list items part of the ListView with a single background, and the background didnot cover the header view. Like a header view of '口' above the body of ListView '目' combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic example of the power of Android's ListView. you have a case where different list items have different views (in your case the only different is the background).
I recommend you to view Google I/O 2010 video about [listviews](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=wDBM6wVEO70) mainly you need to focus around `getViewType` method